# Legend related to span

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add a legend which explains what each span represents in the figure and I'm having trouble to find out how to do that, since I'm new to Python/matplotlib.

So, I don't want a legend which explains each of the lines in my graphic, but I want to split the graphic using spans in different color and explain what each color (span) means.

How to do that?

I'm using this to add the spans, just to avoid confusion:

```
ax.axvspan(10, 300, alpha=0.2, color='red')
```

---

I'm adding an example to make things more clear. Instead of Men and Women there should be some other text and appropriate colors.

[image: With legend]

Answer (score 1):

Since the legend you want does not seem refer to the actual data but some properties in your plot, I'd recommend to use [`pylot.text` or `pyplot.annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text). With these commands you can freely position your "legend".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I create "legend-like" look in that way (easily, if possible)? So I would like to have colored rectangles and text next to them, how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [this annotations guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html) which highlights some very nice legend-like examples that will surely fit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, non of this fixes my problem. I don't want arrows and text spread apart, I want to create visualization as a legend. Is that even possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this particular section](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#placing-artist-at-the-anchored-location-of-the-axes)? The way you worded your question this could solve your problem. Else we might need some clarification (maybe an mspaint sketch?)

Comment: Please check out my edited question. Since I have multiple classes what happens is that labels for each class get put on top of each other when using your link, and there is no information about the correlation to the colors. As I said, I'm new to Python and pyplot, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a label to the span:

```
ax.axvspan(10, 300, alpha=0.2, color='red', label="left span")
```

Then the legend will automatically pick it up, assuming you're using one of the automatic methods of doing it (e.g. `ax.legend()`)